# Get value from STUFF function in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this query:

```
SELECT STUFF(
(
    SELECT ' '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), R.ID)+' '+O.DisplayName+' : '+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), R.Value)
    FROM AA_V_PHR_CCD_ResultsXResults R 
        INNER JOIN AA_V_PHR_CCD_ResultsObservationXLANGUAGES O
        ON R.IDResultObservation = O.ID 
    WHERE IDResults = @ID_ESAME   AND O.IDLanguage = 2
    FOR XML PATH('')

), 1, 1, '') [data];
```

Now I should to execute this query from my Store Procedure. This query result this Message:

```
data
1604 HBsAg : 0.140 1605 HBsAb : 0.000 1606 HCV : 0.020
```

Now I want to put this result in my variables to execute other operation, so I have do this:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @TEXT AS NVARCHAR(4000)
SELECT TEXT = STUFF(
(
    SELECT ' '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), R.ID)+' '+O.DisplayName+' : '+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), R.Value)
    FROM AA_V_PHR_CCD_ResultsXResults R 
        INNER JOIN AA_V_PHR_CCD_ResultsObservationXLANGUAGES O
        ON R.IDResultObservation = O.ID 
    WHERE IDResults = @ID_ESAME   AND O.IDLanguage = 2
    FOR XML PATH('')

), 1, 1, '') [data];

END
```

But if I try to execute this code I have an error message:

> Incorrect syntax near to 'data'.

Comment: do you need the ;?

Comment: just remove [data] @ the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the alias:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @TEXT AS NVARCHAR(4000)
SELECT TEXT = STUFF(
(
    SELECT ' '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), R.ID)+' '+O.DisplayName+' : '+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), R.Value)
    FROM AA_V_PHR_CCD_ResultsXResults R 
        INNER JOIN AA_V_PHR_CCD_ResultsObservationXLANGUAGES O
        ON R.IDResultObservation = O.ID 
    WHERE IDResults = @ID_ESAME   AND O.IDLanguage = 2
    FOR XML PATH('')

), 1, 1, '') [data];

END
```